# Prove: If $x$ is not a left zero divisor and $xy=1$, then $yx=1$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and let $x,y \in R$ with $xy = 1$. Assume
that $x$ is not a left zero-divisor. Prove that $x$ is a unit.

$$xy = 1$$

$$\begin{gather}
xyx = x \\
xyx - x = 0 \\
x(yx-1) = 0
\end{gather}$$

Since $x$ is not a left zero divisor, $yx-1 = 0$.

Thus $yx=1$.

As $xy=1$ as well, $x$ is a unit.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: Looks good to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct.

(I'm posting this CW answer to get this off the unanswered queue.)